# Laravel login issues, signed as an user but shows session data of other user

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I have got a problem on my website.
When I log into my site sometimes it shows other users information.
Suppose there are there users, X, Y Z. When X login using his email and passwords after logging he shows logged in users name is Y or Z. But it not happening always. 
 Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: without any code we cannot do anything to help you. Did you tried debugging your code?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.3